# Order of Traversal in Bidirectional Dataflow Analysis

Tags: compilers, graph-traversal, program-optimization, data-flow-analysis

Does order of traversing CFG matter in solving bidirectional dataflow problems, from a performance perspective?

Comment: What do you think? Please add your proof of work or thoughts _in the question_.